# Help with the proof of the Urysohn metrization theorem in James Munkres's Topology, page 215.

Tags: general-topology

I don't understand how we're able to apply the Urysohn lemma in Step 1 when the given space $X$ is only regular, and not normal.

Comment: Look at theorem 32.1 at page 200: regular and second-countable implies normal.

Comment: Duh. Thanks so much.